# site has a background image - cannot remove it from the editor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm moving from FCK editor to CK editor 3.6.3 and the site has a background image, which is appearing in the CK editor. I need to remove this while using the same CSS file for both the general site and the CK editor (to pick up on CSS for the styles dropdown).

I tried setting config.BodyClass to a style with no  image - this works on FCK2.x but not the CK3. I also found via google a config.extraCss setting but I don't see it in the docs, and it does not appear to do anything  anyway.

Fullpage is off (i.e. editor is not producing `<body><head>` etc tags))

I've got a workaround by having two CSS files, one for the site and one for CK with a different body style, but there must be a better way?

Thanks,
Kevin

Config section:

```
config.stylesSet = 'my_styles:/admin/ckeditor/styles_dropdown.js';
config.contentsCss = '/newdesign/style.css';
//config.extraCss = 'body {background: none;background-image: none;}';
config.BodyClass = 'fckbody' ;
```

CSS section (of the 'main' css file)

```
body{
margin:0px; padding:0px; background-image:url(/newdesign/site_bg19.jpg); repeat; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#393939;
}

.fckbody {
    background-color: white;
    background: none;
    background-image: none;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name in CKEditor is **[bodyClass](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.bodyClass)** with an initial lower case.

Comment: Thank you! I had done a copy n paste from my FCK2.x config after a quick check here - http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/FCKeditor_CKEditor_Configuration_Mapping - I did not notice the change in case of the 'b'

Answer (score 1):

Thought I should post my insight here for my findings. I came across this page while looking for a reason why my CKEditor was showing a background image of my site.

If you CKEditor is showing a background image on the Make a Comment section of a node :

1 - Head to "admin/config/content/wysiwyg"

2 - click edit to the text format for which text format is showing the background image

3 - click the CSS tab drop down

4 - change the Editor CSS to "Editor Default CSS".

Hope this helps someone!